# Autofac register multiple implementation from a single interface

Tags: autofac

How do I register this on Autofac given the code snippet below?

```
public interface IService
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetNames();
}

public class GospelNames : IService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames() { return new List<string>{ "John", "Mark" };}
}

public class CommonNames : IService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames() { return new List<string>{ "Ben", "Matt" };}
}

public class WeirdNames : IService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames() { return new List<string>{ "Weird Al" };}
}

public class BaseImplementation : IService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IService> _services;

    public BaseImplementation(params IService[] services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        foreach(var service in _services)
        {
            results.AddRange(service.GetNames());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

I've been reading about decorator pattern and I'm not sure if this is a candidate to transform into that pattern? Or is this a bad practice?

Comment: [Have you seen this FAQ?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: thanks Travis! i might need to redesign the baseimplementation then just resolve ienumerable<iservice>.